# How do I delete all text before a specific word?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk

```
txt1_response = requests.get("http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/11313/pg11313.txt")
txt1 = txt1_response.text
```

I've read all the text from this url. I want to delete all the text content before the words "ABOUT ANIMALS."

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Find the index of that string in the response then use that index in a slice.  Welcome to SO. PLease take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: Is "ABOUT ANIMALS" in the text of that href link?  I could not find those words together.

Answer (score 0):

txt1[txt1.index('ABOUT ANIMALS'):]